# How to change colour of custom Laravel's directive in PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I have custom directives

```
    \Blade::directive('test', function($expression) {
        return "<?php if (\\code) : ?>";
    });

    \Blade::directive('endtest', function($expression) {
        return "<?php endif; // code ?>";
    });
```

In the editor that directive is white

[image]

How to make PhpStorm recognize and color my directives?

Comment: Have you tried adding your directive to the list of Blade directives in IDE? Open `Settings/Preferences` and look for Blade (use search field to narrow it down).

Comment: Works! Thanks! Do you know how to make some directives different colour from others?

Comment: *"Do you know how to make some directives different colour from others"* IDE has no such option -- all tags are the same.

Comment: That is unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6):

[image]
Follow the screenshot below to add your custom directive

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Blade` and disable the checkbox `Use default settings`. Then switch to the tab `Directives` and add your directive with the equivalent PHP code. This also has the benefit of enabling code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Сlarification

PspStorm Blade plugin does not work with names with "_" in 2020.1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.